# Синтаксис Node.js, mongoose (name: string, schema)

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Прописываю файл User.js

```
const {Schema, model, Types} = require('mongoose')
 
const schema = new Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    links: [{ type: Types.ObjectID, ref: 'Link' }]
})
 
module.exports = model(name: 'User', schema)
```

Проблема такая - в WebStorm не работает подсказка синтаксиса, когда прописываю строчку:

```
module.exports = model(name: 'User', schema)
```

[image: внутренний синтаксис model]

Здесь name: должно становиться серым не редактируемым словом и должно выглядеть вот так:
[image: как должно быть]

Однако ничего не происходит.
И если прописываю name: самостоятельно, то он выделяется как функция, и затем выдаётся следующая ошибка.

```
[0] C:\Users\...\WebstormProjects\...\models\User.js:9
[0] module.exports = model(name: 'User', schema)
[0]                        ^^^^
[0]
[0] SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
[0]     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
[0]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
[0]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
[0]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
[0]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
[0]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\WebstormProjects\...\routes\auth.routes.js:6:14)
[0]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
[0]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
[0]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
[0]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
[0]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\WebstormProjects\...\app.js:7:22)
[0]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
[0] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Пакет mongoose переустанавливал, однако model всё равно работает также. Облазил интернет в поиске решения, но так и не нашёл способа. Я совсем новичок в Js и поэтому мгу чего-то не знать. Прошу отнестись с пониманием)

Пробовал прописывать последнюю строчку так:

```
module.exports = model('User', schema);
```

Да, тогда Web Storm не помечает файл, как файл с корявым синтаксисом, но выдаётся ошибка:

```
[1] > react-scripts start
[1]
[0] C:\Users\...\WebstormProjects\...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:475
[0]       throw new TypeError('Invalid value for schema path `' + fullPath +
[0]       ^
[0]
[0] TypeError: Invalid value for schema path `type`, got value "undefined"
[0]     at Schema.add (C:\Users\...\WebstormProjects\...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:475:13)
[0]     at new Schema (C:\Users\...\WebstormProjects\...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:129:10)
[0]     at Schema.interpretAsType (C:\Users\...\WebstormProjects\...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:955:29)
[0]     at Schema.path (C:\Users\...\WebstormProjects\...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:676:27)
[0]     at Schema.add (C:\Users\...\WebstormProjects\...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:498:12)
[0]     at new Schema (C:\Users\...\WebstormProjects\...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema.js:129:10)
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\WebstormProjects\...\models\User.js:3:16)
[0]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
[0]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
[0]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
[0]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
[0]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\WebstormProjects\...\routes\auth.routes.js:6:14)
[0]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
[0] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: а разве там `Types.ObjectID` а не `Types.ObjectId` должно быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте написать вот так убрав из импорта Types:

```
links: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Link' }]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: @zakh не за что, слева от ответа есть галочка, это лучшая благодарность)